# Как получить значение включен виджет TextView или нет (false|true)?

Tags: android, textview

Как получить значение включен виджет TextView или нет (false|true)? Проверка состояния виджета необходима для включение условия
if (TextVew enabled true|false) {
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (textView.isEnabled()) {
   //enabled
   }
else{
   //disabled
}
```